# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SmartyException: unable to write file

Tags: php, smarty, rhel

In my PHP application, I came across this error

```
         [21-Mar-2022 06:41:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SmartyException: unable to 
         write file /var/www/html/Cache/Templates/wrt62381e27dc68c in 
         /var/www/html/AP_Framework/Php/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php:44
         Stack trace:
         #0 
         /var/www/html/AP_Framework/Php/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(201): 
         Smarty_Internal_Write_File::writeFile('/var/www/html/C...', '<?php /* Smarty...', 
         Object(AP_SmartyTemplate))
```

I changed permission to 775, 755, and 777 to the Cache folder but still, it's not working at all.
Can anybody have any idea on this? I didn't installed smarty yet. Do I need to install it on my remote linux server?

Comment: The error is a permission one, did you give permissions to the folder and recursively? Looks like it's trying to write in a sub-folder called Templates

Comment: share ls -lR on that folder to check the sub-levels

Comment: Check [NGINX and PHP-FPM. What my permissions should be?](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be)

Comment: You will need to make sure that wrt62381e27dc68c has the 'w' bit set for 'other'.  You could use chmod o+w on that file.  If the file is autogenerated by another script/program you'll need to make it's configured to generate files that are writable by 'other'.